# IllegalArgumentException on Android when sort files by their name, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, comparison, comparator

Why the code below will throw the IllegalArgumentException and is there any test cases for me to reproduce this exception:

The platform is Android and you can get the device info on the exception:

Time Of Crash      : 2021-07-08 21-45-13
Device Manufacturer: Google
Device Model       : Pixel 5
Android Version    : 11
Android SDK        : 30
App VersionName    : 2.0.1
App VersionCode    : 121

The algorithm I write:

```kotlin
/** File name comparator. */
class FileNameComparator(private val caseSensitive: Boolean = false) : Comparator<String> {

    override fun compare(left: String, right: String): Int {
        val csLeft = left.toCharArray()
        val csRight = right.toCharArray()
        var isNumberRegion = false
        var diff = 0; var i = 0; var j = 0
        val lenLeft = csLeft.size; val lenRight = csRight.size
        while (i < lenLeft && j < lenRight) {
            val cLeft = getCharByCaseSensitive(csLeft[i])
            val cRight = getCharByCaseSensitive(csRight[j])
            val isNumericLeft = cLeft in '0'..'9'
            val isNumericRight = cRight in '0'..'9'
            if (isNumericLeft && isNumericRight) {
                // Number start!
                if (!isNumberRegion) {
                    isNumberRegion = true
                    // Remove prefix '0'
                    while (i < lenLeft && cLeft == '0') i++
                    while (j < lenRight && cRight == '0') j++
                    if (i == lenLeft || j == lenRight) break
                }
                // Diff start: calculate the diff value.
                if (cLeft != cRight && diff == 0) diff = cLeft - cRight
            } else {
                if (isNumericLeft != isNumericRight) {
                    // One numeric and one char: the longer one is backwards.
                    return if (isNumberRegion) { if (isNumericLeft) 1 else -1 } else cLeft - cRight
                } else {
                    // Two chars: if (number) diff don't equal 0, return it (two number have same length).
                    if (diff != 0) return diff
                    // Calculate chars diff.
                    diff = cLeft - cRight
                    if (diff != 0) return diff
                    // Reset!
                    isNumberRegion = false
                    diff = 0
                }
            }
            i++; j++
        }
        if (i == lenLeft) i--
        if (j == lenRight) j--
        return csLeft[i] - csRight[j]
    }

    private fun getCharByCaseSensitive(c: Char): Char
            = if (caseSensitive) c else if (c in 'A'..'Z') (c + DIFF_OF_CASES) else c
}
```

And the exception throw is:

```
********* uncaught exception *********
Time Of Crash      : 2021-07-08 21-45-13
Device Manufacturer: Google
Device Model       : Pixel 5
Android Version    : 11
Android SDK        : 30
App VersionName    : 2.0.1
App VersionCode    : 121

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
 at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899)
 at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516)
 at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:457)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:254)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1492)
 at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1470)
 at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:206)
 at f.s.o.a(SourceFile:1)
 at h.a.e.j.i.g(SourceFile:14)
 at h.a.e.j.i$c.a(SourceFile:3)
 at h.a.e.j.i$c.doInBackground(SourceFile:1)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 ... 4 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
 at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899)
 at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516)
 at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:457)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:254)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1492)
 at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1470)
 at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:206)
 at f.s.o.a(SourceFile:1)
 at h.a.e.j.i.g(SourceFile:14)
 at h.a.e.j.i$c.a(SourceFile:3)
 at h.a.e.j.i$c.doInBackground(SourceFile:1)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: This is not Java -- Kotlin perhaps?

Comment: And does your code obey the transitive property for comparison?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it's Kotlin. So far, only one user tell me the exception. So seems it only throw the exception on rare cases.